# setting on TargetSkd in Android App does insure that the app will work in every previous version?

Tags: android

setting the targetsdk to 19 in my App and the minSdkVersion to 15 does ensure that my App works correctly on every previous targets (above the minSdkVersion) 18, 17 ? or we should also test our App to work on every other target ?

Comment: This is explained in the documentation: `minSdkVersion` = The lowest API level with which your app is compatible, `targetSdkVersion` = The highest API level against which you’ve designed and tested your app.

Comment: Ok, that's mean you have also to test the App for every version above you minSdkVersion, is that right?

Comment: Ideally you should test on as many many devices and OS versions (among those that you support) as possible. Perhaps https://firebase.google.com/docs/test-lab/ would be of use to you if you feel that you need to scale up your testing.

Comment: thank you so much for your responding.

Answer (score 0):

By specifying sdk version, you can not be sure, that will work in all versions above minimum sdk or not.

Android have some specific improvements time by time and also remove some old methods from code.

For old methods( **depricated**) you should change your code. You must ensure that you are using latest code.

Also ensure that, the code you have wrote is usable in older versions. Some of code not useful in prelollipop device, like transition animations. Android studio is great application, it also suggest method is deprecated for deprecated methods and also suggest code is only useful after android lollipop device.

**When you writing code always check warning displayed by IDE .**

I hope this helps you.